# How to uninstall Office 2013 without the original installer?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

I have a Office 2016 on my PC, but the ancient Office 2013 wasn't uninstalled and I removed the temporary install files so I don't have the installer to remove the program from my computer. I've searched the MSDN Download Center but only found the latest Office 365 online installer.

When I go to https://products.office.com/en-US/microsoft-office-2013:

> **Download Office 2013**
>
> To download and install Office 2013 for a single PC or Mac go to
> MyAccount

In my Account I have only Office 2016, so I think I'll never get the Office 2013.

**How can I uninstall this program from my computer?**

Comment: I did this a month ago or so. I had 2013, installed 2016, then my defaults went to 2013 when I did something. Just go to "Installed Programs" and uninstall the one that isn't 2016 by visually inspecting your installed programs list. You might have to choose "repair" if uninstall isn't available.

Comment: I cant uninstall via program files, because I removed the installed from the temp cash, so now the uninstall fails.

Comment: Temporary Cache shouldn't play a role in this. Try repair and try again. Deleting program files is a no-no; unless you are manually setting folders yourself for a programming project like Android or JDK manual drop-in files. Always use Uninstall.

Comment: by temp cash i mean default install /setup folder location on the system disk where all installers keeps its files...I can't run repair, as the setup file missing it can't even run the dialog window

Comment: Do a New install.

Comment: And that is Not a temporary cache. Nothing tem and nothing cache.

Comment: @ejbytes... How do you want me to do a new install if my question is that I have no setup (impossible to obtain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the original installation media/download to remove your broken Office 2013 installation.  Instead, you can download and run Microsoft's [Completely uninstall Office 2013 with the easy fix tool](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#OfficeVersion=2013) (Option #2 in the linked page).

If that doesn't work, this link has instructions for how to [manually uninstall Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manually-uninstall-Office-2013-4e2904ea-25c8-4544-99ee-17696bb3027b#officeversion=2013).  Normally I would quote the steps here in case the source link breaks, but there's three possible uninstall routines each comprising 20+ distinct steps.